# Caching mysql database with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to provide a caching layer for mysql database on my node.js server app.

The caching should be able to hold array objects (not just a key-value store).

What module should I use for it ?

Currently i'm using those modules:

express

socket.io

mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this module : https://github.com/guggero/node-mysql-cache

The problem is that I do not not how stable it is..